# How to bind the label Values to a Tab Container in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```css
lblEmail.Text=dt.Rows[0]["Email"].ToString();
```

```html
<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
<cc1:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="2" Width="256px" ForeColor="Blue" Height="250px">
  <cc1:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel1" ID="TabPanel1">
    <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Email") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
  </cc1:TabPanel>
</cc1:TabContainer>
```

I am Unable to bind the label Data to tab Container.. It is showing null

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Text = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Email" %>'
```

Comment: Showing this Message....System.Web.UI.Control' does not contain a definition for 'DataItem' and no extension method 'DataItem' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?